# Compiler encoding system-specific file separator

Tags: java, maven

I have the following java code:

```
public interface Defaults {
  public static final String DIR_PATH = "a/b/c/";
  File DIR_FILE = new File(DIR_PATH);
}

public class Main {
  public File directory = Defaults.DIR_FILE;
}
```

This was compiled on a windows machine and deployed to our local nexus repository. It was then executed during a maven build on a linux machine. I end up with `main.directory.list()` returning null. Using **mvnDebug**, I see that the path of the File is actually `a\b\c`! If I use the debugger to change the directory to `new File("a/b/c")`, then my code works.

Why did the compiler encode system-specific separators? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike what everyone else tells you, this is unrelated to Windows and `File.separator`.

`String DIR_PATH = "a/b/c/"` is just a String, neither Java nor the compiler make any attempt to understand what it could mean, so you get the same value both on Windows and Linux.

Also note that `/` works as a file separator both on Unix and Windows, so this isn't an issue either. When necessary, Java will convert `/` to `\`.

`File DIR_FILE = new File(DIR_PATH);` is a constant but `new File()` is still executed by the VM at runtime when the class is loaded. So the path is **not** converted to Windows format while the *compiler* generates byte code.

So the problem you describe must be elsewhere or an important part of the code example you posted was changed when you simplified it for the question. My guess is that someone put a Windows-style path into the code elsewhere or maybe the config and you overlooked this.

That said, a safe way to build paths is to use `File(File, String)`:

```
File DIR_PATH = new File( "a", new File( "b", "c" ) );
```

This will always build a path that works, no matter what the file separator is. If you must, you can use

```
File DIR_PATH = "a" + File.separator + "b" + File.separator + "c";
```

but that can fail for more complex examples and it's more text to read.

Answer (score 2):

Yes use [`File.separatorChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar)

> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 this; you shouldn't use `System.getProperty()` for this. Always use `File.separator` and `File.separatorChar`: They are much faster, type safe, easier to read, typo-safe, avoid string literals.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks your statement makes total sense, updated answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use platform independent file/directory separators like [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String DIR_PATH = "a"+File.separator"+"b"+File.separator+"c"
```

Comment: -1 Don't use `System.getProperty()` for this. Always use File.separator and File.separatorChar: They are much faster, type safe, easier to read, typo-safe, avoid string literals.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Why? This advice contradicts your own answer, which is correct. There is no need to use backslashes *or* `File.separator` in Java. `/` always works.

Comment: @EJP: Sorry, my comment is missing an "If you'd do this at all, use `java.io.File.separator` ..."